# Вывод данных из связанных таблиц php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Имеются 2 таблицы, категории и продукты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал запрос, аналог full outer join. Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT C.name, P.name FROM categories C 
LEFT JOIN products P ON 
C.id = P.id_cat 
UNION ALL 
SELECT C.name, P.name FROM categories C 
RIGHT JOIN products P ON 
C.id = P.id_cat 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM categories C WHERE C.id = P.id_cat);
```

Но данные из таблицы категории дублируются. Вопрос в том, как в php избавится от дублирования этих значений чтобы получился массив такого вида:

`['Холодильники' => ['Bosch kgn39', 'Atlant nf340']];`

Comment: в php пробежаться циклом и собрать новый массив, который вам нужен

Comment: Но тогда получается мне можно просто сделать 2 запроса на вывод категорий и продуктов. А потом сделать цикл в цикле, и проверять по id. Но это ведь не эффективно...

Comment: Как мне в одной итерации закидывать в ключ 'Холодильники' сразу несколько значений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$query = [
    ['c_name' => 'Холодильники', 'p_name' => 'Bosch kgn39'],
    ['c_name' => 'Холодильники', 'p_name' => 'Atlant nf340'],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $result[$row['c_name']][] = $row['p_name'];
}

print_r($result);
```

Вывод

```
Array
(
    [Холодильники] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bosch kgn39
            [1] => Atlant nf340
        )

)
```

Comment: То что нужно.... Спасибо огромное. А я вокруг, да около ходил....